# WordPress WooCommerce custom payment gateway development issue

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to set title for my payment gateway, but on the checkout form the title doesn't appear. Is there any way to set an option to imitate settings saving, but only for one option (title)? Because if I set in `payment_fields` function (on checkout load), it doesn't work.

```
function *****_init_payment_class() {
    ...
    class ****Payment extends WC_Payment_Gateway {
        ...
        public function payment_fields() {
            $res = $this->sendRequest('GET', "payment-service/view/$this->payment_service_id");
            if($res['_statusCode'] == 200) {
                $paymentService  = $res['data'];
                $this->title = $paymentService['name'];
```

...\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\templates\checkout\payment-method.php

```
<li class="wc_payment_method payment_method_<?php echo esc_attr( $gateway->id ); ?>">
<input id="payment_method_<?php echo esc_attr( $gateway->id ); ?>" type="radio" class="input-radio" name="payment_method" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $gateway->id ); ?>" <?php checked( $gateway->chosen, true ); ?> data-order_button_text="<?php echo esc_attr( $gateway->order_button_text ); ?>" />

<label for="payment_method_<?php echo esc_attr( $gateway->id ); ?>">
    <?php echo $gateway->get_title(); /* phpcs:ignore WordPress.XSS.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped */ ?> <?php echo $gateway->get_icon(); /* phpcs:ignore WordPress.XSS.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped */ ?>
</label>
<?php if ( $gateway->has_fields() || $gateway->get_description() ) : ?>
    <div class="payment_box payment_method_<?php echo esc_attr( $gateway->id ); ?>" <?php if ( ! $gateway->chosen ) : /* phpcs:ignore Squiz.ControlStructures.ControlSignature.NewlineAfterOpenBrace */ ?>style="display:none;"<?php endif; /* phpcs:ignore Squiz.ControlStructures.ControlSignature.NewlineAfterOpenBrace */ ?>>
        <?php $gateway->payment_fields(); ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

So here basically I see *<?php echo $gateway->get_title();* code, where I expect my title to be. But it's actually empty. I want to set title in payment_fields() hook/function. Is there a way to do it?

[image]

Comment: Check: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/payment-gateway-api/